# How do you log in from work using your personal account while you are already logged into Google?

Tags: support, login, usability, authentication, google-openid

I have a personal Stackoverflow account with points and stuff. I want to log in with that. I normally authenticate with Google.

My work uses Google apps and I have a Google work address.

How do I log into (other) Stack sights using my personal Google account?

When I click the Google authentication, it asks if I want to log in using my work email. I want to keep them separate.

I saw 'More Options' and another Google icon, and it asked

> Enter your Google Profile username:

But when I entered my personal Google login email, which is not Gmail, it gave this error:

> Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
>   No OpenID endpoint found.

Comment: Have you considered using a second openID to login?

Comment: @yoda I don't know what you mean. I don't want to create another profile, because I already spent a lot of time adding information to my personal Stack profile.

Comment: Do you use a personal Gmail address for authentication of your personal account?  Or another OpenID provider?

Comment: @psubsee2003 I use neither a personal Gmail address nor another OpenID provider. I log into Google using my own custom email address.

Comment: @Chloe If you go to [your profile](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/201166/chloe) and click on "My Logins", you should see an option to add another open id. This is not a new account, but just a new login option — kinda like a duplicate key to your house.

Comment: @yoda Great! That worked! I added a login and now I have two emails under "My Logins" and I can log into my normal account from work! So, the information is totally separate, right?

Comment: @Chloe what info is separate?  You mean the accounts?  No, they are a single account with 2 logins.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add another login to your list of Google accounts, you should be able to select the account you want to use for OpenID authentication when you click the "log in with Google" option:

[image: log in with Google OpenID option]

…which will give you your list of available accounts:

[image: list of Google accounts]

To add a new account, you can click your avatar on any Google page (or the new tab page of Chrome):

[image: Google profile list with add account option]

This should allow you to remain logged in to your company's Google account for company-related stuff, while still being able to access your personal Stack Overflow account.

The other option is to simply use your work account as an OpenID login for your existing Stack Exchange account, which is covered in [the help center topic on managing logins](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials).

Comment: Other options: different browsers, incognito mode + fresh login.

Comment: @MonicaCellio It's on a Mac using Safari and I don't think it has incognito mode.

Comment: @Chloe and no other browser?  (Maybe IT doesn't let you install Firefox or Chrome?)  Anyway, from the acceptance I gather that this answer worked for you; glad to hear it.