# Log in with the Google Account of your choice?

Tags: feature-request, android-app, login, user-accounts, google-openid

I signed up to Stack Overflow and other related Stack Exchange websites using an old Google account which I still use for programming related communities.

Nonetheless, I am signed in with another Google account on my cellphone which I use for my personal needs.

When I come to log in to my Stack Exchange account with the mobile application, I can't use my Google account currently used on Stack Exchange as I do on PC, that is, adding an account to my Google logged in profiles, and choosing which I want to log in with onto the Stack Exchange mobile application.

I would like to be able to choose to log in with another Google account just as it seems possible with the OpenID authentication.

Besides, these questions sound similar:

- [google - gmail account problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212358/google-gmail-account-problem)
- [How do you log in from work using your personal account while you are already logged into Google?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197185/how-do-you-log-in-from-work-using-your-personal-account-while-you-are-already-lo)

As for the second, I guess this is what I use to do, log in into both my Google accounts and choose which to use to log in to Stack Exchange. And I can't seem to find a way with the Stack Exchange mobile application.

If this is not possible yet, it could prove to be valuable to the mobile app, I guess (reason why I tagged my question also as a *feature-request*).

Comment: iOS app or android app?

Comment: Android application. I edited my tags accordingly.

Comment: @WillMarcouiller I have the same problem: my Android phone is synchronized with another google account and I can't log in with the other one... Have you solved this problem?

Comment: Not yet, as it seems the concern is out of scope in a SE point of view. Perhaps if this question generates enough activity to attract SE's administrators' attention? I hope so. Perhaps upvoting it, or else, continue commenting to keep it on top of actuality so that others with the same problem may act as well...

Comment: @WillMarcouiller With the last version of Gmail I've resolved this problem. I added a new Gmail account and now the StackExchange app ask me to choose what account use to log in. Maybe this is not the best solution but at least it works ;)

Comment: Any new of this since its initial post?